# Nav Bar disappearing on popviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

On one of my views, when a button is pressed I call another view that is a `SplitViewController`.  If this `SplitViewController` is called via one of these buttons I have special objects to add to the view.  mostly just nav bar items, like a cancel button.  This view can be accessed elsewhere and these items are not needed which is why there is the special condition.

However, when the user is done and i pop the `ViewController` back to the previous screen that was selected, the nav bar disappears on that screen.  I am not setting it to hidden nor am I doing anything strange with the nav bar.  Simply adding the `SplitViewController` then popping back.

Some code..

```
//declare the split screen VC
SplitScreenViewController *split = [[SplitScreenViewController alloc] init];

//set the flag that this VC is coming from a button, so we need the extra nav bar items
[split setIsFromButton:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:split animated:YES];
```

now the call back is simply...

```
- (void)cancelSelectionBtnClicked
{
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and when the view returns, the nav bar is gone.

any ideas?

*edit* it should be noted this exact same thing is done elsewhere the same way(as far as I can tell) and the nav bar is visible on return.

Comment: Well, I added in a navbarhidden = NO just to be sure, and that seemed to fix it.   so somewhere the bar is being hidden apparently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your ViewController's `viewWillAppear` you can again make your `navigationBar` visible.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same issue as OP.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen various strange navbar behavior in UISplitViewController's, and in a few cases it was because the controller was not set as the rootViewController of the window as opposed to inside a navigation controller like you have set up.

Comment: The issue is not actually in the UISplitViewController.  It displays fine.  The issue is in the screen that pushes the SplitView onto the navigationController's stack.  When the splitView is popped, the nav bar disappears.

Comment: I understand, but I have seen it interact poorly when below other controllers. Apple says that a split view controller must be the root: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html